# How to design schema, display a message to it's owner, but if owner is unspecified, display to all user?

Tags: mysql, sql, database-design

I have the schema like this,

message

```
+------------+----------+
| id         |  text    |
+------------+----------+
| 1          | message1 |
| 2          | message2 |
| 3          | message3 |
+------------+----------+
```

user_message

```
+------------+-------------+
| user_id    |  message_id |
+------------+-------------+
| 1          | 1           |
| 1          | 2           |
| 2          | 2           |
+------------+-------------+
```

because the message3 is no owner, it owned to all user.

So, the user1 has message1, message2 and message3,

the user2 has message2 and message3.

And I need write the sql to query user1's messages,

```
SELECT 
    *
FROM
    message AS a
        JOIN
    user_message AS b ON a.id = b.message_id AND b.user_id = 1 

UNION ALL 

SELECT 
    *
FROM
    message AS a
        LEFT JOIN
    user_message AS b ON a.id = b.message_id
WHERE
    b.user_id IS NULL
```

Does this design correct?

Or I should add the message3 to all users, like this?

```
+------------+-------------+
| user_id    |  message_id |
+------------+-------------+
| 1          | 1           |
| 1          | 2           |
| 2          | 2           |
| 1          | 3           |
| 2          | 3           |
+------------+-------------+
```

But if I have a new user, I wish the new user own message3, I need to write extra code to do this.

How do I do it correctly?

**EDIT:**

I made a mistake above, I lost a case is one user can has many messages.

As suggested by Neville Kuyt.

I like the "no surprises".

And I change the column name and schema to

message

```
+------------+----------+
| id         |  text    |
+------------+----------+
| 1          | message1 |
| 2          | message2 |
| 3          | message3 |
+------------+----------+
```

user_message

```
+------------+-------------+-------------+
| id         |  user_id    |  message_id |
+------------+-------------+-------------+
| 1          |  1          |  1          |
| 2          |  1          |  2          |
| 3          |  2          |  2          |
| 4          |  null       |  3          |
+------------+-------------+-------------+
```

Now, the query will be

```
SELECT 
    *
FROM
    user_message AS a
        JOIN
    message AS b ON a.message_id = b.id
WHERE
    user_id = 1 OR user_id IS NULL;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Correct" is a tricky thing to get right in schema design. I generally favour the "no surprises" approach - someone should be able to understand what's going on by looking at the schema and the data, without reading the documentation. I also favour "don't repeat yourself".

You offer two candidate solutions.

The first solution contains a surprise - columns with the name "id" are usually the primary key for a table; in this case, the "id" column is actually a foreign key to the "users" table. To reduce this level of surprise, I'd create the column "user_id" to contain the foreign key. If "user_id" is also the primary key in your business domain, you can just rename the column.

The second surprise is that the column contains foreign key data to the user table which don't exist, but which invoke special behaviour - they are sent to all users. A less surprising solution would be for that value to be "null", rather than a non-existent value. When you create user 3, you update the appropriate record in message.

Your schema then becomes

message

```
+----------------+----------+
|    id |user_id |  text    |
+-------+--------+----------+
| 1     |   1    | message1 |
| 2     |   2    | message2 |
| 3     | null   | message3 |
+-------+--------+----------+
```

Your second option contains another surprise - data in "messages" changes as a side-effect of a change to "user" (when you create a new user, you have to delete all the messages to other users with the ID of that user). It has the benefit of being explicit - every message/user combination is stored, but I don't like the side-effect.

Comment: I like "no surprises". I made a mistake above, I lost a case is one user can have many messages. So I edit my post.

Comment: OK - so have you answered your own question?

Comment: I am not sure I do it correctly. As you said, "Correct" is a tricky thing. Your answer improved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `exists` and `not exists`:

```
select m.*
from message m
where exists (select 1
              from user u
              where u.message_id = m.id and
                    u.user_id = 1
             ) or
      not exists (select 1
                  from user u
                  where u.message_id = m.id
                 );
```